# Why is the ID not being found by getElementById() or querySelector() when making a classic editor via CKEditor 5

Tags: javascript, html, svelte, ckeditor5, smui

I want to implement an classiceditor from ckeditor 5, but the id from my div can't be found.
This is the code:

```
ClassicEditor
    // Note that you do not have to specify the plugin and toolbar configuration — using defaults from the build.
    .create( document.getElementById("editor") as HTMLElement )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error.stack );
    } );
```

And the SMUI component I'm using for the editor.

```
<div class="rowmargin">
    <Textfield
    style="width: 100%;"
    bind:value={$s_instruction.Text}
    label="Text"
    variant="outlined"
    id="editor">
    </Textfield>
</div>
```

Also tried just doing this, got the same problem:

```
<div class= "rowmargin" id="editor">  
</div>
```

Would have expected for the classiceditor to appear with in this div.

Comment: Your code is probably executing before the element exists, hence it can't be found.

Comment: Adding onMount() does not fix it sadly.

Comment: Also have tried placing the <script> tag at the bottom of the .svelte file, doesn't help either.

Comment: what about your debugging ?

Comment: delete `as HtmlElement`

Comment: @AlirezaBest, deleting `as HtmlElement` won't do anything except for adding a Typescript compiler error. All it does is to satisfy typescript, nothing more.

Comment: @Roan128 have you tried setting up a variable and just binding that `div` into a variable and passit into the `.create()` instead?

Comment: Debugging gives me a undefined/null object so it isn't getting found. And I have tried binding the div to a variable and passing that as in create(), but it doesn't work to.

Comment: @Roan128 can you produce a small example in a Stackblitz environment?

Comment: does TextField pass the `id` prop to any element for that matter, it does not automatically do that.  In Svelte you should btw opt for using `bind:this` to get DomElements instead of `getElement...` methods

Comment: Hi @Stephane Vanraes, thanks for your solution. Combined with onMount() this worked. I am new to svelte so I did not know about this.